# Do proc rates affect on-crit effects

Tags: diablo-iii

For example [Battle rage](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/battle-rage) with the rune 'Swords to Ploughshares' has an on-crit effect. So if it's used in combination with [Whirlwind](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/whirlwind) 13% [proc rate](http://www.d3maxstats.com/?p=procrates), will the health globe still drop on 8% of the crits or 1.04% (0.13 * .08) of the crits?

Comment: Proc effects can hardly be generalized, if at all. You need to narrow down your question, if you expect it to qualify and find the attraction you think it deserves.

Comment: you should check out this post http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11914351645